# Series label in barchart in dojo

Tags: dojo, bar-chart

I am using Dojo 1.8. Please help me to know how to add series label in barchart in runtime.

Following is the example of static values but what if I have values:"one,two,three,four" in an array. How I will use array in runtime to assign series labels.

`chart.addAxis("x",{
    labels: [
        {value: 1, text: "one"},
        {value: 2, text: "two"},
        {value: 3, text: "three"},
        {value: 4, text: "four"}]});`

Regards
Gaurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `dojo.map()` to form labels:

```
var values = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

chart.addAxis("x", {
  labels: dojo.map(values, function(value, index){
    return {value: index + 1, text: value};
  })
});
```